# Why erase and kill characters do the same thing?

Tags: terminal, stty

Among the `stty -a` settings on my machine there are such as `erase = ^?; kill = ^U;`. The man page reports that

```
   erase CHAR
          CHAR will erase the last character typed

   kill CHAR
          CHAR will erase the current line
```

But I found out the corresponding keyboard shortcuts effectively do the same thing, i.e. when I type `boo` at the terminal and then press `<ctrl>+U` or `<ctrl>+?` the line would be erased completely in both cases.

So why the erase character does not erase only the last character?

Comment: Those settings only applies for commands that don't implement their own line editor. For instance most shells implement their own line editors (and even offer you a choice of several like vi style or emacs/gmacs style).  Where do you observe that behaviour? At the prompt of some shell? Then what shell?

Comment: You'd also want to check that your terminal sends the `^?` character upon pressing Ctrl+? (see with Ctrl+V followed by Ctrl+? for instance).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I use Bash as shell and Gnome terminal as emulator. The Ctrl+V then Ctrl+? examination, indeed, shows that `^_`, not `^?` was sended. But what does this character mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this at my shell prompt and got similar results.  However, closer examination shows an error.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (which you might think is ctrl-?) actually produces ctrl-_ which is typically bound to "undo".   If you want ctrl-? you need to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd>.  You can test this by typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

Note that the stty command affects terminal editing in "cooked" mode where the undo key doesn't work.  So my guess is that you are using a shell like bash that implements its own command line editing, which might honor the stty settings but doesn't have to and adds a lot of fancier editing keys as well.

Comment: I use Bash as shell and Gnome terminal as emulator. The Ctrl+V then Ctrl+? examination shows that `^_`, not `^?` was sended, indeed. Is it possible for bash to address this character itself taking into consideration the cooked mode does not allow input to proceed (=to be read by shell) before EOL was received (i.e. before I push the `enter` key)?

Comment: Bash uses raw mode instead of cooked mode specifically so it can handle keys any way it wants.  If you want to test cooked mode, try `cat` and use ctrl-c or ctrl-d to exit.